# Accessing parent loop id using $parentContext.$index in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout-2.0, jquery-mobile-collapsible

```
<div id="tree"  data-role="collapsible-set"  data-bind="foreach:VM1.Folders"> **Parent Loop**
      <!--Top level Folder-->
      <div data-role="collapsible" class="Folder" data-bind="attr:{'id':$index()}">   
        <h3><span data-bind="text:name"></span></h3>

            <!--Sub Folder start-->
             <div data-bind="attr:{'id':'subtree'+$index()} ">   
           <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->                  
              <div data-bind="foreach:VM2.SubFolders" data-role="collapsible-set">
                   <div data-role="collapsible" class="SubFolder"
                   data-bind="attr{'id':$parentContext.$index}"> **This gives undefined**                               
                            <h3><span data-bind="text:name"></span></h3>
                   </div>
               </div>   
           <!--/ko-->                
             </div>
           <!--End Of Sub Folder-->
      </div>
    <!--End Of Top level Folder-->

</div>
```

I am using knockout foreach binding to create jquery mobile collapsible items dynamically
facing problem when accessing parent loops `$index()`.
I tried both `$parentContext.$index()` and `$parentContext.$index`. Both are giving 'undefined'. I am using stop binding, is it because of that it is not able to get parent loop index?
Following is my code.

Comment: Simply use $parent.$index

Comment: You have a missing colon in:
 
    `data-bind="attr{'id':$parentContext.$index}"`  

Should be: 

    `data-bind="attr: {'id': $parent.$index}"`

Comment: Hi chris Dixon and Steve.. I tried both of your suggestion still it gives 'undefined'

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the line:

```
data-bind="attr{'id':$parentContext.$index}"> **This gives undefined**
```

for:

```
data-bind="attr{'id':$parentContext.$index()}"> **This gives undefined**
```

since $index is observable, just like you did in line 3.